# Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.TridionConfigurationException: Unable to locate java runtime

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I'm having a problem with getting Tridion Content Delivery to run on a .NET implementation.  The error is:

```
[TridionConfigurationException: Unable to locate java runtime]
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.VirtualMachineLoader.FindJavaRuntime(XmlElement virtualMachineConfig) +1516
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.VirtualMachineLoader.SetupJavaVirtualMachine(IJvmLoader loader, String tridionHome, EventLogger eventLogger) +403
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +570

[JuggerNETFrameworkException: Exception occurred during configuration callback]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader(Boolean bEnvOverrides, Boolean bDefaultJvm, TraceFacility fac, TraceLevel level) +869
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.GetJvmLoader() +64
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +119
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +51
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1652
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +61
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +80
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo) +422
   Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Query..ctor() +101
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query..ctor() +32
   DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider.GetContentByUrl(String Url) +162
   DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page) +558
   DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.TridionControllerBase.GetModelForPage(String PageId) +97
   DD4T.Web.Mvc.PageController.LoadFromUrl(String pageUrl) in c:\Projects\blah\DD4T.Web.Mvc\PageController.cs:66
   DD4T.Web.Mvc.PageController.MyPage(String pageId) in c:\Projects\blah\DD4T.Web.Mvc\PageController.cs:61
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +130
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +726390
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +309
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +726324
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Java 6 is installed.
[image]

We've also thoroughly went through this ticket: [An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/972/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-exception-from)

Also verified the usual suspects like making sure app is compiled for 64-bit and .NET Framework is set to 4.0 and Integrated on the App Pool

Answer (score 7):

Check the registry for JavaHome variable.  It should exist and point to your Java 6 installation:
[image]

This variable can be missing or invalid if you had previously installed Java 7, then realized that Tridion 2011 doesn't support Java 7 and downgraded Java.  So clean up the remnant variables from Java 7 and update the registry to 6.